# Intel Edison Modules

Tags: intel, iot, intel-galileo, intel-edison

Is their a way to download ALL the modules downloaded onto the Intel Edison? I've already gotten the MRAA module on it, just need the others such as express, http, socket.io, debug, etc. Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

Better version of the question here: 
[Intel Edison MRAA module not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154300/intel-edison-mraa-module-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the question. But you can "download" any node.js module on your Edison using:

```
npm install <myModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of node modules available in node package manager. If you want to install all modules, it will be unethical. There is not enough memory to install all modules in intel edison. If you need any module, you can install it via npm command. I have given an example below to work on.

```
npm install http
```